# Selecionar um array especifico de um JSON com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, array, funções, axios

Criei um script com axios para retomar uma chamada, então o resultado:

```
[
  {
    FieldId: 8095,
    FieldName: 'Nome1',
    FieldValueIds: [ 12059 ],
    FieldValues: [ '9.000' ],
    IsFilter: true,
    FieldGroupId: 99,
    FieldGroupName: 'Informações'
  },
  {
    FieldId: 8108,
    FieldName: 'Nome2',
    FieldValueIds: [ 2994 ],
    FieldValues: [ 'Frio' ],
    IsFilter: true,
    FieldGroupId: 99,
    FieldGroupName: 'Informações'
  },
  {
    FieldId: 28079,
    FieldName: 'nome3',
    FieldValueIds: [],
    FieldValues: [ '00000' ],
    IsFilter: false,
    FieldGroupId: 1,
    FieldGroupName: 'Categoria'
  }
]
```

Estou usando apenas `console.log(response.data.ProdSpecification)` para trazer o resultado, porém preciso trazer um resultado único.

Por exemplo o `FieldName: 'nome3'` e  `FieldGroupName: 'Categoria'` do `FieldId: 28079`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) e crie uma expressão que verifica o item que satisfaça a pesquisa como descrita na sua pergunta, ***exemplo***:

```js
const data = [{
    FieldId: 8095,
    FieldName: 'Nome1',
    FieldValueIds: [12059],
    FieldValues: ['9.000'],
    IsFilter: true,
    FieldGroupId: 99,
    FieldGroupName: 'Informações'
  },
  {
    FieldId: 8108,
    FieldName: 'Nome2',
    FieldValueIds: [2994],
    FieldValues: ['Frio'],
    IsFilter: true,
    FieldGroupId: 99,
    FieldGroupName: 'Informações'
  },
  {
    FieldId: 28079,
    FieldName: 'nome3',
    FieldValueIds: [],
    FieldValues: ['00000'],
    IsFilter: false,
    FieldGroupId: 1,
    FieldGroupName: 'Categoria'
  }
]

const item = data.find(x => 
    x.FieldName === 'nome3' &&  
    x.FieldGroupName === 'Categoria'
);

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score -1):

eu acho que usando o `Array.prototype.filter()` voce vai conseguir chegar no resultado que precisa.

Ira lhe retornar um novo array das informações que corresponder ao seu filter.

```
meuArray.filter((item) => { item.FieldName === 'nome3' })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter